# SQL query for selecting multiple records for one product for a single id

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

My table looks like this, what I'm trying to achieve is to pull out all the records for one user for the product that have the earliest date

```
product |type_id| user | Date  |Desired ROW_NUMBER as output  |
-------+--------+------+-------+---------------------

 1      |   1  |   A   | 0101  |   1
 1      |   1  |   A   | 0102  |   1
 2      |   3  |   A   | 0105  |   2
 2      |   5  |   A   | 0105  |   2
 3      |   7  |   B   | 0101  |   1
 3      |   8  |   B   | 0104  |   1
```

So I want to pull all the records with "1" in the desired row_num column, but I haven't figured out hot to get this without doing another group by. Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by user order by min_date) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   min(date) over (partition by user, product) as min_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, with only one subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(date) over (partition by user, product) as min_date_up,
             min(date) over (partition by user) as min_date_u
      from t
     ) t
where min_date_u = min_date_up;
```

You can interpret this as "return all rows where the product has the minimum date for the user".

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=782e4ed4d9b7bad8a9e70aba31204006) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks for your help! I guess I need to rephrase a little bit, I would like to have 2 records for product 1, corresponding to date 0101 and 0102, since product 1 is the product that have the earliest date for user A, and the record 0102 is also related to product 1. I think the 2nd solution will only give us 1 record for product 1?

Comment: @Helen . . . No.  Both of these should return all records for "product1".  I added a db<>fiddle, illustrating this.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT * FROM [tableName] WHERE Desired ROW_NUMBER = 1 ORDER BY Date[DESC, ASC]**

Pass the Desired ROW_NUMBER  value dynamically as a parameter.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, the 'desired ROW_NUMBER' is actually a column I would like to create, not an existing one